# Find and extract content of division of certain class using DomXPath

Tags: dom, domxpath

I am trying to extract and save into PHP string (or array) the content of a certain section of a remote page. That particular section looks like:

```
<section class="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Student Club</h1>
            <h2>Subtitle</h2>
            <p>Lore ipsum paragraph.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

And since I can't narrow down using class container because there are several other sections of class "container" on the same page and because there is the only section of class "intro", I use the following code to find the right division:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.remotesite.tld/remotepage.html");
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$intro = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'intro')]");
```

And at this point, I'm hitting a problem - can't extract the content of $intro as PHP string.

Trying further the following code

```
foreach ($intro as $item) {
                    $string = $item->nodeValue;
                    echo $string;
                }
```

gives only the text value, all the tags are stripped and I really need all those divs, h1 and h2 and p tags preserved for further manipulation needs.

Trying:

```
foreach ($intro->attributes as $attr) {
                $name = $attr->nodeName;
                $value = $attr->nodeValue;
                echo $name;
                echo $value;
            }
```

is giving the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$attributes in
```

So how could I extract the full HTML code of the found DOM elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew I was so close... I just needed to do:

```
            foreach ($intro as $item) {
                $h1= $item->getElementsByTagName('h1');
                $h2= $item->getElementsByTagName('h2');
                $p= $item->getElementsByTagName('p');
            }
```